# Moved registrars/DNS, now site is unavailable for most?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

I've had a site up for a client at http://staging.livecurriculum.com for years.  They've managed the DNS on their end, previously through Dreamhost.  They recently moved this domain to NetSol and now the site is unavailable for them and what seems like the rest of the world:

http://isup.me/staging.livecurriculum.com

Strangely, the site resolves and works as expected for me still.

Nothing has changed with the vhost conf.  They've defined "staging" as an A record on "livecurriculum.com" pointing to the IP of the server 96.126.123.156.

What else can be wrong?

FYI, hitting the URL http://staging.livecurriculum.com when you're not logged in will redirect you to https://secure.livecurriculum.com, and we currently have a self-signed cert there.  Just a heads-up on the "Invalid certificate!" warning you'll get.

Comment: The TTL is 7200; did you wait two hours for DNS caching?

Comment: @MichaelHampton they moved DNS weeks or months ago.

Comment: Well, that IP address is not responding. Is there actually a server there?

Comment: Yes, it's very much up and running.  I'm currently clicking through pages on it.

Comment: Firewall ahoy :)

Comment: @NickW Hmmm, lemme look into the iptables

Comment: Smells like an application issue - I can ping the IP and I get a response to a telnet on port 80, but I don't get a response to a `GET / HTTP/1.0` after connecting via telnet. Did you recently push a new version or otherwise restart services?

Comment: Scratch that - my proxy was responding for port 80. I now agree, it looks like a firewall.

Comment: Responding for me.

Comment: @NickW Yep, was a bad firewall rule.  I can't decipher iptables so I had our network guy find and fix it.  Thanks!

Comment: No problems, glad it was a quick fix!